# java initialising an arraylist with array.asList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to initialise an arraylist with .asList but I keep gettıng an error
The error is "cannot find symbol".
I want to initialise the arraylist with a few strings.
Here is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SortingArrayListString
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>(Array.asList("xyz", "abc"));

        System.out.println("ArrayList Before: " + test);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `Arrays` (with `s` at the end). Also you will need to import it via `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: thank you so much for your help ıt worked

Comment: @Pshemo can you write your response as answer?

Comment: @SezinKarli No, questions about typographical errors are off-topic on Stack Overflow and should be closed (and IMO deleted since they are not about real programming problems). I don't want to encourage others to post answers to such questions just to gain reputation by posting one myself.

Answer (score 3):

Note that right class would be [`java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

---

#### Some tips about your code

Take a look at the JavaDoc of [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)): it provides an example on how you should work.

1. Keep variables as general as possible.

   ```
   List<String> test;
   ```
2. Are you going to change the list later? If you aren't, you don't even need to create a new object through the `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E>)` constructor.

   ```
   List<String> test = Arrays.asList("xyz", "abc");
   ```
3. You might want to parameterize any `ArrayList`.

   ```
   new ArrayList<String>();
   ```

Comment: 2--You would need to do that if you ever wanted to modify the list, since Arrays.asList() returns a java.util.Arrays.ArrayList which is immutable.  3--the abbreviated syntax is fine.

Comment: @MattPutnam Improved.

Comment: "*In the future, remember to always parameterize any ArrayList. `new ArrayList<String>();`*" OP is using `new ArrayList<>` which lets compiler infer generic type based on reference so there is no need to write it as `new ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: @Pshemo However it improves readability.

Comment: It depends. If I have something like `Map<String,List<Map<String,List<Integer>>>> mapping` then I prefer `new HashMap<>()` over `new HashMap<String,List<Map<String,List<Integer>>>>()`.